# read file and processing the data with pthread

Tags: parallel-processing, pthreads

I have some `.txt` data files, I have processed them serially. I want to use 'pthread' to parallel process them. Then could I send the thread with data file name, and process the data within the thread, and wait all threads finished, merge the all results? Could you give me some advice about that, please? Thanks?

Comment: Simply creates two threads and joins them

http://www.amparo.net/ce155/thread-ex.html

Comment: To close the question, I took my comment to the answer part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following site provides a pthread example. It simply creates two threads and joins them

- http://amparo.net/ce155/thread-ex.html